# C# Compiler Optimization

Tags: c#, optimization, compiler-optimization

Why does the compiler do to optimize my code?

I have 2 functions:

```
public void x1() {
  x++;
  x++;
}
public void x2() {
  x += 2;
}
public void x3() {
  x = x + 2;
}
public void y3() {
  x = x * x + x * x;
}
```

And that is what I can see with ILSpy after compiling in Release mode:

```
// test1.Something
public void x1()
{
    this.x++;
    this.x++;
}

// test1.Something
public void x2()
{
    this.x += 2;
}
// test1.Something
public void x3()
{ 
    this.x += 2;
}
// test1.Something
public void y3()
{
    this.x = this.x * this.x + this.x * this.x;
}
```

x2 and x3 might be ok. But why is x1 not optimized to the same result? There is not reason to keep it a 2 step increment?
And why is y3 not `x=2*(x*x)`? Shouldn't that be faster than `x*x+x*x`?

That leads to the question? What kind of optimization does the C# compiler if not such simple things?

When I read articles about writing code you often hear, write it readable and the compiler will do the rest. But in this case the compiler does nearly nothing.

---

Adding one more example:

```
public void x1() {
  int a = 1;
  int b = 1;
  int c = 1;
  x = a + b + c;
}
```

and using ILSpy:

```
// test1.Something
public void x1()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 1;
    this.x = a + b + c;
}
```

Why is it not this.x = 3?

Comment: What makes you believe that `x=2*(x*x)` is more optimized than `x = x * x + x * x`? Readability or reduction in terms does not mean the formula operations are more optimized, sometimes expanding it means its more optimized.

Comment: 1. Most optimizations are performed by the JIT compiler at run-time and not by the C# compiler.
2. Your suggested optimization for `x1` is not functionally equivalent in the face of multithreading (if the field were volatile, for example, the compiler is definitely *disallowed* from performing the suggested optimization).

Here's an admittedly old article on the optimizations the C# compiler does perform: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do.aspx

Comment: Less code does not mean better performance

Comment: Also, x++ is special case because it involves caching the value to be returned and then incrementing it.

Comment: Are 2 multiplications not faster than 2 multipications and a addition?

Comment: The C# compiler also isn't a computer algebra system, so it can't perform arbitrary algebraic manipulations to minimize the number of operations.  I'm always surprised by how many people don't seem to realize this.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler cannot perform this optimization without making an assumption that variable `x` is not accessed concurrently with your running method. Otherwise it risks changing the behavior of your method in a detectable way.

Consider a situation when the object referenced by `this` is accessed concurrently from two threads. Tread `A` repeatedly sets `x` to zero; thread `B` repeatedly calls `x1()`.

If the compiler optimizes `x1` to be an equivalent of `x2`, the two observable states for `x` after your experiment would be `0` and `2`:

- If `A` finishes before `B`, you get `2`
- If `B` finishes before `A`, you get `0`

If `A` pre-empts `B` in the middle, you would still get a `2`.

However, the original version of `x1` allows for three outcomes: `x` can end up being `0`, `1`, or `2`.

- If `A` finishes before `B`, you get `2`
- If `B` finishes before `A`, you get `0`
- If `B` gets pre-empted after the first increment, then `A` finishes, and then `B` runs to completion, you get `1`.

Answer (score 4):

`x1` and `x2` are NOT the same:

if `x` were a public field and was accessed in a multi-threaded environment, it's entirely possible that a second thread mutates `x` between the two calls, which would not be possible with the code in `x2`.

For `y2`, if `+` and/or `*` were overloaded for the type of `x` then `x*x + x*x` *could be different* than `2*x*x`.

The compiler will optimize things like (not an exhaustive list my any means):

- removing local variables that are not used (freeing up registers)
- removing code that does not affect the logic flow or the output.
- inlining calls to simple methods

Compiler optimization should NOT change the behavior of the program (although it does happen).  So reordering/combining math operations are out of scope of optimization.

> write it readable and the compiler will do the rest.

Well, the compiler may do *some* optimization, but there is still a LOT that can be done to improve performance at design-time.  Yes readable code is definitely valuable, but the compiler's job is to generate *working* IL that corresponds with your source code, not to change your source code to be faster.

Comment: I added a new example that has nothing to do with multithreading? --- By the way, if the compiler can reorder instruction to optimize performance and you need to take special actions like MemoryFences to prevent that, why is combining x++ and x++ different? Without locks or MemoryBarriear I would expect that the compiler does not care about multithreading.

Comment: I think you're expecting too much of the compiler.  Its job is to turn your source code into working IL, not to find every potential place that your code _could_ be faster and re-code it for you.  If you feel that this is a valuable feature of the next C# compiler then post it on http://connect.microsoft.com and see what happens.

Comment: >>"but the compiler's job is to generate working IL that corresponds with your source code, not to change your source code to be faster."<< I think the idea of an optimizer is to optimize for performance.

Comment: Plus, why stop there?  Why not change your `List` to an `array`?  Why not change your series of `if` statements to a `switch`?  Or remove an `if` block altogether if the condition could never be true?  That's a lot of logic to build into a compiler that many would complain isn't fast enough already.

Comment: The base answer to our question is:  any feature has to be designed, coded, tested, documented, and supported, all of which costs time any money that many other features are competing for.  If the _benefit_ of such a feature does not outweigh the costs (or if other features provide more benefit) then it does not get produced.  My guess the benefit of such an optimization is minimal.

Comment: @bebo The compiler generates IL, which it doesn't even try to optimize. It's the JIT's job to perform platform-dependent optimization on this. It's possible some architectures will execute `x++; x++;` faster, and other architectures will execute `x += 2;` faster. That being said, I doubt the JIT would perform this particular optimization, it's not something that would show up in real code. BTW the compiler doesn't inline calls, but the JIT definitely does it.